# Will endless list in OCaml eat up all the memory?

Tags: ocaml

We can construct an endless list like this:

```
let rec endless = 1::endless
```

I think it would eat up all the memory, but when I tried in `utop`, it doesn't seem so.

`utop` shows the list has been constructed:

> val endless : int list =
>   [1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;    1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;     1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1;    1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;    1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;    1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;    1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1;    1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
>   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; ...]

When I try to apply `List.length`, of course, it never stops due to the fact it has infinite number of `1`s.

---

**Q:**

1. How does OCaml handle endless list?
2. Why it won't give a out-of-memory error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no knowledge of OCaml, so I can't tell you how OCaml handles the implementation, but I can give you a general idea.

Theoretically seen you can have an endless list with just one element, pointing to itself as the next and previous node. This is just a matter of the data structure design.
So, the needed memory to store an endless list would come down to one element and two pointers, both pointing at the same element.

Therefore it uses almost no memory, but it is impossible to count for algorithms that navigate the list nodes by following the next/previous pointers.

Comment: yes, it is implemented as a singly-linked list; no previous pointer exists as to preserve the functional copies.

Answer (score 9):

In OCaml, lists are [single linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). Your `endless` is represented in memory as a self-recursive cons cell

```
.--------.
|        | 
|  +---+-|-+
`->| 1 | * |
   +---+---+
```

Comment: You hard typed the diagram?

Comment: @JacksonTale yes, but not today :) I already played with recursive lists, so it is copy-pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457414/how-to-generate-recursive-list-in-ocaml